# How does Rails View Helper work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I recently came across a tricky situation related to rails view helpers.
The situation is like follows-

I am having a controller as `Feature1::Feature1.1::Feature1.1.1Controller`.
The `Feature1.1` also includes other controllers like `Feature1.1.2Controller`, `Feature1.1.3Controller`...

So ofcourse related view helpers in folder `app/helpers/feature1/feature1.1/...`

Now the real problem I am facing is that a few helpers for `feature1.1` includes the same method name `method1` with related definition.

I was wondering how rails identifies all these helpers as I am noticing that the `method1` i.e. being called in a view for the controller `feature1.1.1` is using the definition of the `method1` i.e. written for the controller `feature1.1.2`.

So does rails consider all helper modules defined in one folder as one?

In a view `feature1/feature1.1/feature1.1.1/index` I am making a method call for `method1`.

I am using `rails3`

Comment: Where are you including the view helpers?

Comment: I am using the default setting which includes all helper by default

Comment: Of course. To access helpers in controllers you need to include but from the views they are globally available. I don't think there is an easy solution to your predicament, looks like you will have to abstract the helpers into an OO layer using a gem such as [Cells](https://github.com/apotonick/cells) - check out https://apotonick.wordpress.com/2011/10/05/rails-misapprehensions-helpers-are-shit/ for an in-depth review of this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some research and would like to share some additional info.
As per @slowjack2k mentioned, view helpers are included by rails as a default behavior.
But my question was about the situation of same method names across multiple helpers.
I found [this](http://www.rails-dev.com/custom-view-helpers-in-rails-4) article to be useful in this scenario. Though it explains the behavior for `Rails 4` but I found it behaves in the same fashion for `Rails 3.2.2`.

I will summarize the article -

> If there will be any conflict in the same names of methods in different helper modules, rails will use method from latter file (alphabetically)

Answer (score 2):

It depends a little bit on your Rails version. With eralier Rails versions, Rails did only include `application_helper.rb` and `<controler_name>_helper.rb`. 
Additional helper modules can be included via `helper :helper_name1, :helper_name2, ...` within your controller.

With later Rails  verions (4.2.?  and up, maybe previous versions too), Rails includes all helpers within your helper folder at once. You can set `config.action_controller.include_all_helpers = false`  within `application.rb` and you will fall back to the old behaviour.

This makes the helper only available within your views. If you want to use a helper within your controller you still have to include your helper with `include XXXHelper`.